# How to pass boost callback as a parameter to method?

Tags: c++, boost, parameter-passing, boost-asio

I can not pass one of the boost callback into my method.

Short story:
I am trying work with `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`
I wrapped socket into my class `SerializationSocket`.

At some point I need to work with async accepting, that's why I need to pass callback into `SerializationSocket`.

Server part:

```
void accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{}

SerializationSocket socket(1950, accept_handler);
```

SerializationSocket:

```
typedef void (SerializationSocket_cb)
     (const boost::system::error_code&, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket);

...

SerializationSocket::SerializationSocket(int port,
    SerializationSocket_cb cb) {
    ...
    acceptor.async_accept(*mp_Socket, cb);  // this line is SerializationSocket.h:44
}
```

Error message says to me that something wrong with my `cb` type:

```
/home/Common/Libs/boost_1_67_0/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp: In instantiation of ‘typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<WriteHandler>::type, void(boost::system::error_code)>::return_type boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol>::async_accept(boost::asio::basic_socket<Protocol1>&, AcceptHandler&&, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Protocol, Protocol1>::value>::type*) [with Protocol1 = boost::asio::ip::tcp; AcceptHandler = void (*&)(const boost::system::error_code&, boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>); Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<WriteHandler>::type, void(boost::system::error_code)>::return_type = void; typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Protocol, Protocol1>::value>::type = void]’:
../../Common/SerializationSocket.h:44:45:   required from here
/home/Common/Libs/boost_1_67_0/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_type_requirements.hpp:105:6: error: static assertion failed: AcceptHandler type requirements not met
      static_assert(expr, msg);
      ^
/home/Common/Libs/boost_1_67_0/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_type_requirements.hpp:214:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS_ASSERT’
   BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS_ASSERT( \
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/Common/Libs/boost_1_67_0/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1262:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘BOOST_ASIO_ACCEPT_HANDLER_CHECK’
     BOOST_ASIO_ACCEPT_HANDLER_CHECK(AcceptHandler, handler) type_check;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/Common/Libs/boost_1_67_0/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_type_requirements.hpp:228:36: error: too few arguments to function
         boost::asio::detail::lvref< \
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           asio_true_handler_type>()( \
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
             boost::asio::detail::lvref<const boost::system::error_code>()), \
```

Here is the boost documentation that I [use](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html). When I use `accept_handler` directly like `acceptor.async_accept(*mp_Socket, accept_handler);` it works.

Comment: The callback only takes one parameter, but your typedef is for a function type that takes two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is to be found in [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html). It's pretty straightforward

> The function signature of the handler must be:

```
void handler( const boost::system::error_code& error );
```

While Your handler has type:

```
typedef void (SerializationSocket_cb) (const boost::system::error_code&, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket);
```

Comment: Hmm. You are right. Now I confused about where I found this strange handler example.